# No Reload After Facebook Login on IE

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using the Facebook PHP SDK and Facebook JS SDK to manage authentication in a web app. The flow should go like this: Click FB login button -> launch OAuth dialog -> enter account details into OAuth dialog -> OAuth dialog closes and web page reloads (now showing content for authenticated user). All pretty standard, I think.

I was originally subscribing to auth.login and auth.logout, and this worked perfectly in Firefox, but in IE 10 it did not reload after the OAuth dialog -- I had to manually reload to view the site as an authenticated user. From testing with alerts (and reading other questions on SO), it appears that Facebook's auth.login event does not fire at all under IE 10 (though auth.logout worked fine). So I switched to subscribing to the auth.authResponseChange event, and it now reloads properly under both Firefox and IE 10.

However, I'm still having the same problem under IE 9: No reload after OAuth closes. The auth.authResponseChange event is recognized, however it does not appear to fire under IE 9 until after a manual reload of the page. Obviously, as much as we'd all love to drop it, IE 9 is used widely enough that supporting it is not optional, and requiring a manual reload after login is unacceptable.

I believe my code is good, as it works properly in other browsers and the code triggered by the auth.authResponseChange event runs correctly even in IE 9 once the event is triggered -- the problem is that for some reason, the event just isn't triggering until after a manual reload. Still, here is my FB init code for reference:

```
<!-- START FACEBOOK CONNECT -->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
function setCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function clearCookie(name) {
    setCookie(name,"",-1);
}

// Main init code
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId      : '<?=$vt->conf->fb->appID?>',
        channelUrl : '//<?=$vt->conf->domain?>/fb_channel.html',
        status     : true,
        cookie     : true,
        xfbml      : true
    });

    // Additional init code here
<?php if ($page->vt->auth->usingFacebook) { ?>
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
        if (response.status != 'connected') {
            // User has been logged out
            //console.log('FB: logout');
            alert('FB logout');
            clearCookie('vt_fbat');
            window.location.reload(true);
        }
    });
<?php } else { ?>
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
        if (response.status == 'connected') {
            // User has been logged in
            //console.log('FB: login');
            alert('FB login');
            setCookie('vt_fbat',response.authResponse.accessToken);
            window.location.reload(true);
        }
    });
<?php } ?>
    //
    //
    //FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
    //  alert('FB: login');
    //  console.log('FB: login');
    //  console.dir(response);
    //  setCookie('vt_fbat',response.authResponse.accessToken);
    //  window.location.reload(true);
    //});
    //FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
    //  console.log('FB: logout');
    //  clearCookie('vt_fbat');
    //  window.location.reload(true);
    //});
};

// Load the SDK Asynchronously
(function(d){
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
}(document));
</script>
<!-- END FACEBOOK CONNECT -->
```

Since it works in other browsers and I've double-checked the source under IE 9 to be sure, I'm confident the PHP is working properly, but just so you know: It uses PHP to fill in the App ID and channel file URL. Also, to print different JavaScript depending whether the PHP SDK detects being logged into Facebook already. If we're already logged in to Facebook, it's watching for a logout; if we're not, it's watching for a login. This is necessary because of switching to auth.authResponseChange, which fires all the time.

I've read multiple related questions on SO and tried everything I can think of, but I just can't get this to work under IE 9. Can anyone make any suggestions?

Comment: Does auth.statusChange have the same effect?

Comment: Using auth.statusChange seems to behave the same as auth.login. It works in neither IE 9 nor 10.

Comment: then i fear polling FB.getLoginStatus() after click is your only way to go now ... :(

Comment: Not sure if that will work -- doesn't the result of getLoginStatus get cached?

Comment: would make it a bit un-useful, i always use getloginstatus in ie at login

Comment: I tried polling getLoginStatus, and I keep getting back "unknown" -- even after logging in. The FB Login button isn't changing to show the message with my friends faces like it does in other browsers, either. Any idea what might be the problem?

Comment: Correction -- this works great in IE 8 & 9. If you want to post FB.getLoginStatus as an answer, I'll mark it accepted. However... it still doesn't work under IE 10, which is a problem. Any ideas would be appreciated.